# Real-time Registry Monitoring

Tags: windows-7, security, monitoring, windows-registry

Does anyone have a good tool for silent, real-time, system-wide registry monitoring?

All of the tools I've seen have one of two problems:

1. They poll for changes, instead of get events in real-time
2. They can't be run without an intrusive GUI (procmon!!)

This seems like it would be a simple and straightforward utility and yet I haven't been able to find one yet, which surprises me.

Thanks!

Note: This is for Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Take a look at the NirSoft registry tools http://www.nirsoft.net/windows_registry_tools.html  especially  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html   Be aware that because of their nature most NirSoft tools trigger anti-virus. I have been using them for years and have seen no adverse effects, but decide for your self.

Answer (score 2):

[Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) has a GUI as you mentioned.

And it also has a feature called "Boot Logging", which turns Process Monitor into a driver that monitors everything silently until you start it again and disable it.

[image: Process Monitor Boot Logging]

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to the GUI problem. You run the application as service in Session 0.

There is an program that allows you to access Session 0 GUIs so you can interact with them as needed.

http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/SwitchToSession0/

Comment: interesting! wasn't aware of that capability. Is there anything special that needs to be done to run it as a service? I tried a few different ways to install exe as a service (nssm, sc, srvany, etc) without any luck, but I might have been doing it wrong...

Comment: Sorry, I've never had a need to use it or install my own service. I stumbled upon it (or a similar piece of software) years ago and thought it was interesting. I wish I had an answer for you.

Comment: @BlindWanderer, What is this program all about? It says "Unable to start Switch To Session 0:

This application will not run on this version of Windows because Session 0 is not available here."